# Open a window after the mainWindow and activate it

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In my application is required the user to select an item from a list before continues uses the application.

To do this, I have a window with the desired items and I display it when the MainWindow displays.

```
public MainWindow() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var itemsWindow = new ItemsWindow();
    itemsWindow.Show();
}
```

The problem is that the window opens in background. How can I open the window in foreground?

The preferable would be to open the itemsWindow on applications start up and onClose event of itemsWindow to display the mainWindow, but I think this approach is far away from my knowledge. Nevertheless, I would appreciate it if someone could post something for how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ShowDialog()` method instead. That way, you won't have to worry about activating that window and user won't be able to interact with `MainWindow` until `ItemsWindow` has been closed.

### Example:

```
var itemsWindow = new ItemsWindow();
itemsWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks decyclone. I thought it was harder than this :)